# Use existing Static library in C++ WinRT UWP app

Tags: c++, uwp, c++-winrt

I have an existing third-party static library that I want to use in my project C++WinRT UWP app. Can I do that?

I have read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/how-to-use-existing-cpp-code-in-a-universal-windows-platform-app?view=msvc-170). But it has me confused.

Documentation talk about "Using a native C++ static library in a UWP App" what is a native c++ library?.

Also, I do not have the source code for this library.

Comment: "Native C++" is redundant. C++ is a native language (as opposed to an interpreted language or a JIT language). The article is talking about native languages in general but focuses on C++. Whenever it says "Native C++" you can just pretend it says "C++". The article also assumes you have the source code for the library and is giving guidance on how to modify the library so it can work in UWP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary limitation for UWP is that the library:

(a) Must use the subset of Win32 imports that are supported for use in WINAPI_PARTITION_APP

(b) It needs to have been built with VS 2015 Update 3 or later in order to be 'binary compatible' with modern Visual C++ tooling used for UWP.

(c) Some APIs that are used by the static library may not be supported in the "AppContainer" security context (i.e. they may fail in ways the code doesn't handle gracefully).

You should also use `/NODEFAULTLIB:kernel32.lib` to avoid having your static library force the import of non-supported APIs. The "WindowsApp.lib" umbrella library provides everything that's supported.

More than likely, you'll need the static library built with some modification to actually link successfully and eventually pass WACK.

Comment: This is so many limitations and so many places it can go wrong. So best option to go for UWP would be only when vender has provided UWP consumable lib. I just wonder why it was made difficult, I am guessing we are getting better security? And maybe some future roadmap that Microsoft is planning? Because this is putting such a limitation on the widespread adaptation of UWP.

Comment: With Win32 "classic" applications if you download some random thing off the internet, then run its installer it will have administrator rights and can do basically whatever it wants to your system. Even just running a Win32 "classic" application as a Standard User has *full access* to every document and file the user has on the machine. The design of UWP is supposed to make it easier to download and run programs with at least some idea of what it's actually doing... You can certainly make a judgement call on how well the *implementation* of UWP achieves that goal, but that's a big part of it.

Comment: What about WinUI3 - Can I use native C++ library in a WinUI3 project without recompiling it specifically for WinUI3?

Answer (score -1):

> I have an existing third-party static library that I want to use in my project C++WinRT UWP app. Can I do that? Also, I do not have the source code for this library.

Yes. You don't need the source code to use a library.

You can just use the binary library ( the final output from the source ) that is provided. It can be included as either `a static or dynamic library` in your final output binary.

> How to include that?

Referring to some portion from the doc for your `third party static library` that may help.

```
To use a native C++ static library in a UWP project
In the project properties for the UWP project, 

choose Configuration Properties > Linker > Input in the left pane. 

In the right pane, add the path to the library in the Additional Dependencies property. 

For example, for a library in the project that places 
its output in <SolutionFolder>\Debug\MyNativeLibrary\MyNativeLibrary.lib, 
add the relative path Debug\MyNativeLibrary\MyNativeLibrary.lib.

Add a include statement to reference the header file to your pch.h file (if present), 
or in any .cpp file as needed, and start adding code that uses the library.

C++

Copy
#include "..\MyNativeLibrary\MyNativeLibrary.h"
```

Comment: This is glossing over **loads** of vital details. See [Chuck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71003005/1889329) to learn what this proposed answer is missing.